# How to enable non working touchpad?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, touchpad, synaptics

I can't set up touchpad driver. My notebook - ASUS X550L. It doesn't work! I go to mouse/touchpad, but touchpad tab isn't here. I try to install synaptic - nothing happens, manuals tell me to change xorg.conf, but it's empty. Why is xorg.conf empty? What must I do?

More ... cursor goes left on about 10 pixels every 5 seconds, is this because the disabled touchpad?

xinput list:

```
horo@X550LN:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: post output of "xinput list"

Comment: here is bug record with same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1325881 this might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464935/weird-pointermousetouchpad-functionality-in-ubuntu-asus-x550l

Comment: Also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198/comments/31

Answer (score 0):

Open your BIOS and find Touchpad settings.When u find, it must be advanced so change it to basic.. save and quit.